# Convert osclass htaccess file to web.config to run Php on IIS problem

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, osclass

host=windows

Enabled friendly URLs in osclass, but there is a problem , friendly URLs aren't working, and I know the problem comes from IIS webconfig file. Is there anyone using osclass on windows? And how does the problem resolve?

I'll give you one of the problematic links :
[https://test.com/search/pattern,تست](https://test.com/search/pattern,%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you enable the friendly URLs, it will add the url rewrite rule into the htaccess file.

IIS [url rewrite rule](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) contains the build-in tool which is used to convert the .htaccess to web.config.

I suggest you could find the htaccess file and add it in below tool.

[image]

[image]